# GNU Radio | Packet Encoder/Decoder | Unwanted bytes added to the transmitted stream

Tags: gnuradio

(A follow up question can be found here: [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56321/gnu-radio-transceiver-loopback-adapted-transmission-stops-unexpectedly))

In an attempt to understand how the packet encoding blocks work I tried to mimic the experiment performed by Aaron, published in [this](http://aaronscher.com/GNU_Radio_Companion_Collection/Packet_encode_decode.html) post, but reduced the flowgraph to the components that interested me the most, namely the `Packet Encoder`, the `Packed to Unpacked` and the `Packet Decoder`. I have also used a text file `in_strings.txt` instead of the `cat_in.png`.

Follows the flowgraph I have  implemented:

[image]

**My expectation:** I was hoping that `out.txt` (File Sink) would be equal to `in_strings.txt` (File Source).

**What really happened:** `out.txt` is very similar to `in_strings.txt` but it contains additional unwanted `x` characters that show up after 65535 expected characters.

Follows a preview of the diff side by side between the input and the output:

[image]

Follows the `in_strings.txt` file: https://pastebin.com/NWa7NEww

I wonder why those `x`'s show up in the output?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packet Encoder and Decoder are broken; they drop data.

That's why they are in the **deprecated** category (for years now!). We've removed them, because as a project, GNU Radio has not been able to fix them (and also, they were terrible from an architecture point of view).

So there's exactly one solution: don't use packet encoder / decoder.

Comment: thanks! What are the alternative blocks and which would be the equivalent flowgraph?

Comment: Depends! I'd probably go for the  architecture you find in the GNU Radio examples, typically installed to `/usr/[local/]/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/packet`, especially packet_rx.grc, packet_tx.grc and packet_loopback.grc