# GNU Radio | Transceiver loopback adapted | Transmission stops unexpectedly

Tags: digital-communications, gnuradio

(This is a follow up question to a previous question: [link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56163/gnu-radio-packet-encoder-decoder-unwanted-bytes-added-to-the-transmitted-str))

I have implemented a flowgraph of a transceiver loopback inspired by the examples found at `gnuradio/gr-digital/examples/packet`, with a slight change - instead of driving the `Packet_tx` with:

- `Message Strobe > Random PDU Generator > Packet_tx`

I am using:

- `File Source (/tmp/in_strings.txt) > Throttle > Stream to Tagged Stream > Tagged Stream to PDU > Packet_tx`.

Then the data is recovered by the `Packet_rx` with:

- `PDU to Tagged Stream > File Sink (/tmp/out_strings.txt)`

Flowgraph below:

[image]

**My expectation:** I was hoping to transmit most of the data from in_strings.txt to out_strings.txt

**What really happened:**

- Chunks of data are lost during transmission in an intermittent fashion. Diff below:

[image]

- Transmission stops unexpectedly after ~40kB.

**The files involved in this experiment:**

- [loopback3.grc](https://pastebin.com/raw/FYJJnUF9)
- [in_strings.txt](https://mega.nz/#!ipcGXSxB!sxLkB1HFpj553xtWRs45hnn5tkQJLLrAs2BtaAfrmKI)
- [out_strings.txt](https://pastebin.com/9HvRBenG)
- packet_tx.grc, packet_rx.grc: `gnuradio/gr-digital/examples/packet`

I wonder what may be the cause of this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: You are lacking the repeat option in the file source. Also, could you please share your GRC code ? The links you uploded are dead

Comment: Sort of... Those blocks simply don't work the way we expect. I had to dig in to those blocks and create my owns.